# Cordova - Changing tabstrip Icons

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1, icons

In my Cordova App, I have a tabstrip with 2 buttons for home and settings. I first used the data-icon attribute to display icons in these buttons, but since Windows Phone doesn't support font icons, I tried using png files. I added img tags inside each tabstrip button and change the icon to the active/inactive color every time a button is selected.

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="tabstrip" id="tabsptrip" data-select="onSelect">                    
                <a href="views/home.html" id="homeTabstrip"><img id="homeIcon" src="Images/Icons/home_active.png" height="35" width="35" />Start</a>
                <a href="views/Settings.html" id="settingsTabstrip"><img id="settingsIcon" src="Images/Icons/gearwheel_inactive.png" height="35" width="35" />Einstellungen</a>
            </div>


function onSelect(e) {
            debugger;
            console.log(e.item[0].id);

            if (e.item[0].id == "homeTabstrip") {
                $('#homeIcon').attr("src", "Images/Icons/home_active.png");
                $('#settingsIcon').attr("src", "Images/Icons/gearwheel_inactive.png");
            } else {
                $('#homeIcon').attr("src", "Images/Icons/home_inactive.png");
                $('#settingsIcon').attr("src", "Images/Icons/gearwheel_active.png");
            }
        }
```

Now, when I first load the app, the correct icons as specified in the html are displayed. When I go the settings page, the icons are exchanged correctly and the gearwheel_active.png and home_inactive.png icons are displayed. But when I go back to the home page, the icons don't change. The src is correctly updated, the icons displayed are still gearwheel_active.png and home_inactive.png instead of gearwheel_inactive.png and home_active.png.

The image files exist (because they are displayed correctly, when the app first starts) and no error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the css instead of changing the image source via jquery.

Here is my Code:

```
<div data-role="tabstrip" id="tabstrip" data-select="onSelect">                    
                    <a href="views/home.html" id="homeTabstrip">Start</a>
                    <a href="views/Settings.html" id="settingsTabstrip">Einstellungen</a>
                </div>
```

and the css:

```
#tabstrip .km-icon {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#homeTabstrip.km-state-active span.km-icon {
    background-image: url("../../Images/Icons/home_active.png");
}

#homeTabstrip .km-icon {
    background-image: url("../../Images/Icons/home_inactive.png");

}

#settingsTabstrip.km-state-active span.km-icon {
    background-image: url("../../Images/Icons/gearwheel_active.png");
}

#settingsTabstrip .km-icon {
    background-image: url("../../Images/Icons/gearwheel_inactive.png");

}
```